# EPPlus exporting slowly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I am using EPPlus to create an exporting reporting system from our database for our users. This system was working very well(fast and didn't timeout) in testing for when there were only 4-5 columns and pulling roughly 500-1,000 rows. But now I am trying to scale it to production needs, which is roughly 29 columns and at most 5k-6k rows. I tried running a report with an expected return of ~1,000 rows of data and now it never seems to finish the export (Meaning waiting longer than 10+ minutes, before giving up or it timing out). From reading up on EPPlus, this shouldn't be an issue for it, as I've noticed many other users are exporting number of cells in the millions.

```
ws.Cells[StartRow, 28].Value = b.scope;
ws.Cells[StartRow, 29].Value = b.lost_city;
StartRow++;
 }

var fileName = "Sample.xlsx";
var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
pck.SaveAs(fileStream);
fileStream.Position = 0;

var fsr = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType);
fsr.FileDownloadName = fileName;
return fsr;
```

Comment: Does not seem like a ton of data.  Which line is it hanging on?  Is the production server the same as your test server?  If not, could it be something with that?

Comment: Which version of EPPlus are you using? We had a similar problem with older version of EPPlus, but it was fixed when updating to v 4.0.4.

Comment: It isn't immediately obvious how your code relates to your question.  Can you post a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?